# Como esconder barra lateral e vertical com CSS

Tags: html5, css3

Gostaria de esconder essas duas barras (Vertical e Horizontal), configurei meu arquivo .css com as definições abaixo, mas não estão funcionando:

```
@charset "UTF-8";

section#conteudo{
  width: 1000px;
  margin:  auto;
}

iframe#frameEspecificacoes{
  width: 400px;
  height: 280px;
  border: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

iframe#frameEspecificacoes::-webkit-scrollbar { 
  display: none;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tentaste usar `overflow: hidden;`?

Comment: É o que estou usando em iframe#frameEspecificacoes. E não dá certo.

Comment: O elemento que contêm o iframe tem que ter o `overflow:hidden` tambem

Comment: Não funcionou, acabei de adicionar...

Comment: Verifica qual elemento está com as barras de rolagem, pois certamente não é o iframe, como Section tem largura de 1000px verifica se o elemento Pai do Section não é o que está estourando.

Comment: Comigo também não funcionou nesse exercício, talvez não seja a melhor forma, mas só consegui esconder a barra de rolagem usando o parâmetro/atributo (scrolling="none") dentro da tag iframe. Ex.: <iframe src="google-glass.html" scrolling="no" name="janela" id="frame-spec"></iframe>

Comment: Também só consegui acrescentando scrolling="no" na tag <iframe ..., ficando da seguinte forma: <iframe src="google-glass.html" name="janela" id="frame-spec" scrolling="no"></iframe>

Answer (score 6):

É necessário verificar qual elemento está *estourando*, ou seja, tendo sua largura/altura excedida pelo tamanho do conteúdo, e aplicar `overflow: hidden;` a esse elemento:

```css
body {
 overflow: hidden;
}

section#conteudo{
 width: 1000px;
 margin: auto;
 overflow: hidden;
}

iframe#frameEspecificacoes{
  background: #AAA;
 width: 400px;
 height: 280px;
 border: none;
 overflow: hidden;
}

iframe#frameEspecificacoes::-webkit-scrollbar { 
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<section id="conteudo">

<iframe id="frameEspecificacoes"></iframe>

</section>
```

Comment: Não está estourando, acredito eu, porque o width está em 900px, do conteúdo restante da página, olhando melhor o que me parece está acontecendo é o não reconhecimento do ::-webkit-scrollbar, que o código fica com cor branca, como se não estivesse sendo reconhecido. Será?

Answer (score 3):

Boa noite galerinha, fiz esse curso e passei pelo mesmo problema, já dei uma resposta aqui no fórum para incluir `<iframe scrolling="no">` na página **specs.html**.

Hoje vim dar a resposta ainda melhor, a solução "semanticamente correta" que é insirir

```
body {
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

no css da página **google-glass.html**.